# Using rank() with subset

Tags: r, subset

I got this data here:

```
           State Abb Region Change
3         Arizona  AZ   West   24.6
6        Colorado  CO   West   16.9
10        Florida  FL  South   17.6
11        Georgia  GA  South   18.3
13          Idaho  ID   West   21.1
29         Nevada  NV   West   35.1
34 North Carolina  NC  South   18.5
41 South Carolina  SC  South   15.3
44          Texas  TX  South   20.6
45           Utah  UT   West   23.8
```

I'm trying to extract a subset where Change > 40.
When I use

```
subset(uspopchange, rank(Change)>40)
```

it works
but when I use

```
subset(uspopchange, Change > 40)
```

it comes up with nothing.
Furthermore, if I use

```
subset(uspopchange, Change > 16.9)
```

it works also.
Why does it do that? Why do I need to user `rank()` to get my subset?

BTW: the data is from

```
install.packages("gcookbook")
```

Comment: Well in your sample data that would be an empty subset, would it not?  None of the `Change` column is greater than 40.

Comment: Can you explain in words what your desired subset is? Can you explain in words what you think rank() does and what Change > 40 means in the context of subset()?

Comment: Actually you are right, I did not notice that. I was working from an example in a textbook. To answer your question, I don't know what rank does. I tried to read up on it, but Im still not fully sure what that subset with rank is trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> library(gcookbook)
> data(uspopchange)
> head(uspopchange[order(uspopchange$Change,decreasing=TRUE),])
            State Abb Region Change
29         Nevada  NV   West   35.1
3         Arizona  AZ   West   24.6
45           Utah  UT   West   23.8
13          Idaho  ID   West   21.1
44          Texas  TX  South   20.6
34 North Carolina  NC  South   18.5
```

There are no rows with `Change` greater than 40. When you are using `rank(Change) > 40` in your `subset()`, it is giving you the rows that, based on the value of `Change`, have a rank higher than 40. Since there are 50 rows in your data (`Change` has a length of 50), you are getting the rows that rank 41, 42, 43, ... , 50.

```
> Top10 <- subset(uspopchange, rank(Change)>40)
> Top10[order(Top10$Change,decreasing=TRUE),]
            State Abb Region Change
29         Nevada  NV   West   35.1
3         Arizona  AZ   West   24.6
45           Utah  UT   West   23.8
13          Idaho  ID   West   21.1
44          Texas  TX  South   20.6
34 North Carolina  NC  South   18.5
11        Georgia  GA  South   18.3
10        Florida  FL  South   17.6
6        Colorado  CO   West   16.9
41 South Carolina  SC  South   15.3
##
> uspopchange[order(uspopchange$Change,decreasing=TRUE),][1:10,]
            State Abb Region Change
29         Nevada  NV   West   35.1
3         Arizona  AZ   West   24.6
45           Utah  UT   West   23.8
13          Idaho  ID   West   21.1
44          Texas  TX  South   20.6
34 North Carolina  NC  South   18.5
11        Georgia  GA  South   18.3
10        Florida  FL  South   17.6
6        Colorado  CO   West   16.9
41 South Carolina  SC  South   15.3
```

Those are equivalent.